# How to avoid file open method in a function

Tags: python

I have this script that works as expected.

https://github.com/shantanuo/Spell-Checker/blob/master/main.py

But it is very slow because the csv file needs to be opened for each and every word.

```
reader = csv.reader(open("en_bigram.csv"), delimiter = ' ')
```

I guess, I need to move that line out of the function. But I am not sure where to place it :)

Comment: add it the main function and pass it as an argument? Or just put fully outside the functions like ```spellchecker```?

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to create a list of words you have used as a class variable and it works as cache?. so, if only the word does not present in the list file reading happens.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Links to offsite resources should never be used for core information. Instead, all information should be provided into the question itself as formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reading all of your offsite code in detail (you should post it here) you would probably be better off using a set to store the words that you read from the CSV file once at setup time. Then you can test for membership of `myword[0]` in the set.

```
with open("en_bigram.csv", newline='') as f:
    en_bigram = {row[0].strip() for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter = ' ')}
```

Then later:

```
if myword[0] in en_bigram:
    result.append(right)
```